# Reconstructing Balances By Weekly Transaction Sums

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for some advice or pointers on how to construct this. I have spent the last year self-learning SQL.  I am at work and I only have access to the query interface in report builder. Which for me means, no procedures, no create tables and no IDE :(. So thats the limitations!

I am trying to reconstruct account balances. I have no intervening balances. I have the current balance and a table full of the transaction history

My current approach is to sum the transactions by posting week (Which I have done) in my CTE named

```
[SUMTRANSREF]
+--------------+------------+-----------+
| TNCY-SYS-REF | POSTING-WK | SUM-TRANS |
+--------------+------------+-----------+
|            1 |         47 | 37.95     |
|            1 |         46 | 37.95     |
|            1 |         45 | 37.95     |
|            2 |         47 | 50.00     |
|            2 |         46 | 25.00     |
|            2 |         45 | 25.00     |
+--------------+------------+-----------+
```

I then get the current balances in another CTE called

```
[CBAL]
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| TNCY-SYS-REF | CUR-BALANCE | CURR-WEEK |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
|            1 | 27.52       |        47 |
|            1 | 52.00       |        47 |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Now I am assuming I could create intervening CTEs to sum and then splice those altogether but is there a smarter (more automated) way?

Ideally my result should be

```
+--------------+-------------+----------+----------+
| TNCY-SYS-REF | CUR-BALANCE | BAL-WK46 | BAL-Wk45 |
+--------------+-------------+----------+----------+
|            1 | 27.52       | -10.43   | -48.38   |
|            2 | 52.00       | 2.00     | -48.00   |
+--------------+-------------+----------+----------+
```

I just am uncertain because each column requires the sum of intervening transactions

```
So BAL-WK46 is (CURR-BALANCE) - SUM(Transactions from 47)
So BAL-WK46 is (CURR-BALANCE) - SUM(Transactions 46+47)
So BAL-WK45 is (CURR-BALANCE) - SUM(Transactions 45+46+47)
```

and so on.

Normally I have an idea where to start but I am flummoxed by this one.

Any help you can give would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You can use an online SQL service to test things out, like https://dbfiddle.uk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some T-SQL that gets the result you require. Should be easy enough to play with to get what you want.

It makes use of Recursive CTE and a PIVOT

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#SUMTRANSREF') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #SUMTRANSREF

IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#CBAL') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #CBAL


IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TEMP

CREATE TABLE #SUMTRANSREF

(
[TNCY-SYS-REF] int,
[POSTING-WK]  int,
[SUM-TRANS] float
)

CREATE TABLE #CBAL
(
 [TNCY-SYS-REF] int ,
  [CUR-BALANCE] float , [CURR-WEEK] int

)

INSERT INTO #SUMTRANSREF
VALUES (1 ,47 , 37.95),
(1 ,46 , 37.95),
(1 ,45 , 37.95),
(2 ,47 , 50.00),
(2 ,46 , 25.00),
(2 ,45 , 25.00 ) 


INSERT INTO #CBAL
VALUES (1,27.52,47),(2,52.00,47);


WITH CBAL AS
(SELECT * FROM #CBAL),

SUMTRANSREF AS(SELECT * FROM #SUMTRANSREF),
RecursiveTotals([TNCY-SYS-REF],[CURR-WEEK],[CUR-BALANCE],RunningBalance) 
AS
(
select  C.[TNCY-SYS-REF], C.[CURR-WEEK],C.[CUR-BALANCE],C.[CUR-BALANCE] + S.RunningTotal RunningBalance from CBAL C
JOIN (select *,-SUM([SUM-TRANS]) OVER (PARTITION BY [TNCY-SYS-REF] ORDER BY [POSTING-WK] DESC) RunningTotal 
from SUMTRANSREF) S
ON C.[CURR-WEEK]=S.[POSTING-WK] AND C.[TNCY-SYS-REF]=S.[TNCY-SYS-REF]
UNION ALL
select  RT.[TNCY-SYS-REF], RT.[CURR-WEEK] -1 [CURR_WEEK],RT.[CUR-BALANCE],RT.[CUR-BALANCE] + S.RunningTotal RunningBalance  FROM  RecursiveTotals RT
JOIN (select *,-SUM([SUM-TRANS]) OVER (PARTITION BY [TNCY-SYS-REF] ORDER BY [POSTING-WK] DESC) RunningTotal 
from #SUMTRANSREF) S ON   RT.[TNCY-SYS-REF] = S.[TNCY-SYS-REF] AND RT.[CURR-WEEK]-1 = S.[POSTING-WK]
)

select [TNCY-SYS-REF],[CUR-BALANCE],[46] as 'BAL-WK46',[45] as 'BAL-WK45',[44] as 'BAL-WK44'
FROM (
select [TNCY-SYS-REF],[CUR-BALANCE],RunningBalance,BalanceWeek from (SELECT *,R.[CURR-WEEK]-1 'BalanceWeek'  FROm RecursiveTotals R
) RT) AS SOURCETABLE
PIVOT
(
    AVG(RunningBalance)
    FOR  BalanceWeek in ([46],[45],[44])
) as PVT
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time on this and I am sure this may be a good answer for some, but I cannot create tables (mentioned in first paragraph of post). I have extremely limited permissions and options!

Comment: Copy everything from under INSERT INTO #CBAL
VALUES (1,27.52,47),(2,52.00,47); and replace the CTE definitions with your own and you will have a working solution.The tempdbs initially are just to re-present the CTE's.no procedures, no create tables :)

Comment: This does exactly what I ask. If anyone is following on from this the only comment I would make is there a couple of slight field naming differences so if you start with my CTE and column names and then use this code you might have to make a couple of changes. But if you use Chris's code 'as-is' with his CTE's then it all works beautifully. thanks for taking the time on this.